# After using IEnumerable in view and controller getting null value in controller(model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc5 in which i am using Ienumerable in View and also in Controller to pass the mutiple values for which i need to use Foreach loop.
After using all this i am getting NULL values in controller from Model

For controller:

```
public ActionResult ManageTimeExpense(IEnumerable<TimeExpense> Timemodel, IEnumerable<ExpenseBook> Expensemodel)
    {
        var get = Request.Files.Count;
        try
        {

                {         
                    //for(var i = Timemodel)


                    foreach(var r in Timemodel)
```

for view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tuple<TimeSheet.Models.TimeExpense , TimeSheet.Models.ExpenseBook>>

@{
    Layout = null;

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageTimeExpense", "TimeExpense", FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        { <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label>Hours:</label>
                        <input id="Hours" name="Hours" type="number" class="form-control hours" placeholder="24 Hours" />
                       @* @Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.Hours, new {@type="number",@class = "form-control",@placeholder="24 Hours", Required = "required" })*@
                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label></label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
```

> ```
> $("#Save").click(function () {
>         var TimeExpense = [];
>         var ExpenseBook = [];
>         var Date = $("#Date").val();
>         var TimeExpenseMasterId = $("#TimeExpenseMasterId").val();
>         $('.invoicerow1').each(function () {
>             var TaskMasterId = $(this).closest('tr').find('.task').val();
>             var Hours = $(this).closest('tr').find('.hours').val();
>             var TimeDescription = $(this).closest('tr').find('. timedes').val();
>
>             TimeExpense.push({
>                 TimeExpenseMasterId: TimeExpenseMasterId,
>                 Date: Date,
>                 TaskMasterId: TaskMasterId,
>                 Hours: Hours,
>                 TimeDescription: TimeDescription,
>
>             });
>         });
>         $('.invoicerow').each(function () {
>             var ExpenseDescription = $(this).closest('tr').find('.exp').val();
>             var Amount = $(this).closest('tr').find('.amt').val();
>             var Currency = $(this).closest('tr').find('.currency').val();
>             var BillStatus = $(this).closest('tr').find('.bill').val();
>
>             ExpenseBook.push({
>                 ExpenseDescription: ExpenseDescription,
>                 Amount: Amount,
>                 Currency: Currency,
>                 BillStatus: BillStatus,
>
>             });
>         });
>
>         var data = {
>             TimeExpense: TimeExpense,
>             ExpenseBook: ExpenseBook
>         };
> });
>       </script>
> ```

Comment: Can you share the full code of the view? In the question it seems to be missing.

Comment: where are you assigning data object value ? you are not positing data object to method

Comment: Foreach calls GetEnumerator method and if Timemodel is null, it returns NullReferenceException. Make sure your modelstate is valid.